# Multiple Scrollbars using jQuery iScrollView library

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscrollview

I want two scrollable div side by side, but the following html is generating scrollbar for first div only with class "ui-block-a".

```
    <div class="ui-grid-b" style="height:100%;margin-bottom:40px;">
        <div data-iscroll="" data-role="content" class="ui-block-a" style="padding-left:40px; padding-right:40px;width:29.95%; max-height:900px;">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed="false">
               <h3>Heading 1st Div</h3>    
               Data in 1st Div
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-iscroll='{"resizeWrapper" : false}'  class="ui-block-b" style="width:68%; padding-left:4%; padding-right:2%; max-height:900px;">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed="false">
               <h3>Heading 2nd Div</h3>
               Data in 2nd Div
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ui-grid-a not -b if you're using two blocks only.

Comment: Yeah I am using custom width thats why.

Comment: U-grid-b is designed for three blocks, use -a and adjust width. Also, try adding to the parent grid, overflow-y: hidden; and to the blocks overflow-y: scroll;